# Proper definitions of resistivity of conductivity

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, conductivity

- Is resistivity the same as specific electrical resistance?
- And conductivity is same as specific conductance when I am dealing with electrical properties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *specific* modifier simply means that stated property per a given quantity, usually mass, usually a gram. In other words resistance or conductance per gram of resisting or conducting material.  But the fundamental definition of the properties for the different word forms of resistance and conductance are not changed by this wording.